# Solving system of linear equations with square roots

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, linear-algebra, gaussian

Say I have a system of linear equations with a square root

```
  1  1  |  1  
  (1/2 + sqrt(5) / 2)  (1/2 - sqrt(5) / 2)  | 1
```

Using np.linalg.solve to solve this system of equations I would normally do

```
vars = [[1, 1], [1/2 + sqrt(5)/2, -sqrt(5)/2 + 1/2]]
outcomes = [1, 1]
solution = np.linalg.solve(vars, outcomes) 
#solution has to be only whole numbers, no crazy decimals. Preferably in the following form
[ sqrt(x), sqrt(y) ]
```

However this returns an error because it doesn't know what to do with the sqrt(). How can I solve this system of equations with square roots and get full numbers back, so no decimals?

Comment: If you want to use `sqrt` you have to import it from `math`. How do you want to express the solution as the square root of a whole number? Try to solve it by hand first.

Comment: `Numpy` is package for doing numeric computation and does not support symbolic computation. You should have a look at [Sympy](http://www.sympy.org/en/index.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure to understand your question, however you can make the script work like this:

```
import math
import numpy as np

vars = [[1, 1], [1/2 + math.sqrt(5)/2, -math.sqrt(5)/2 + 1/2]]
outcomes = [1, 1]
solution = np.linalg.solve(vars, outcomes) 

print("Solutions:", solution)
```

Comment: "Solution has no decimals"? Huh?